# How can i send the below request using axios?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, postman

This request works fine from postman, but i am trying to replicate it from axios but i cannot

[image]

This is what i did (Note that i am getting the same response status, but the language is not being updated on the instance itself)

```
const config = { headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'} };
const lang ="en_US";
  return axios.put("https://add-jira8.infosysta.com/rest/api/2/mypreferences?key=jira.user.locale", lang,config).catch(ex => {
    console.log(ex)
    ErrorLoging.log("AxiosRequests.js >>>>> updateUserLanguage >>>>>> ERROR: " + ex)
  });
```

This is the api endpoint used

[image]

Comment: can you at lease explain why the minus 1, i am really not able to figure out the problem

Comment: upvoted it so it goes back to 0 :D

Answer (score 0):

You have issue in your body even in your postman, you selected json so it should be a json, like:

```js
const API_URL = "https://add-jira8.infosysta.com/rest/api/2/mypreferences?key=jira.user.locale";
const config = { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } };
const body = { lang: "en_US" };
return axios.put(API_URL, body, config)
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    });
```

Comment: i am aware of that, but in postman it is working correctly and i can see the result updating fine, please check my update

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the screenshot you provided the body is sent as "raw" but in your code you are trying to sent JSON. Not sure which one the server accepts but if it expects raw then you should change the content type:

```js
const config = { headers: {"Content-Type": "text/plain"} };
const lang ="en_US";
return axios.put("https://add-jira8.infosysta.com/rest/api/2/mypreferences?key=jira.user.locale", lang,config).catch(ex => {
  console.log(ex)
  ErrorLoging.log("AxiosRequests.js >>>>> updateUserLanguage >>>>>> ERROR: " + ex)
});
```

Comment: I will try this, Thank you @Elvis